# Ansible Имя инстанса AWS

Tags: ansible, amazon-web-services

Я конфигурирую ansible-playbook для создания инстанса aws при помощи boto. Не могу задать имя инстанса, пробовал задать ключом и тагом:

```
 - name: "имя" 
 tags:
   - name: "имя"
```

ничего не получается.

Сам ansible пишет поддерживаемые параметры, что-то похожее на имя я там не наблюда.

```
assign_public_ip, aws_access_key, aws_secret_key, count, count_tag, debug_botocore_endpoint_logs, ebs_optimized, ec2_url, exact_count, group, group_id, id, image, instance_ids, instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior, instance_profile_name, instance_tags, instance_type, kernel, key_name, monitoring, network_interfaces, placement_group, private_ip, profile, ramdisk, region, security_token, source_dest_check, spot_launch_group, spot_price, spot_type, spot_wait_timeout, state, tenancy, termination_protection, user_data, validate_certs, volumes, vpc_subnet_id, wait, wait_timeout, zone"
```

Может кто сталкивался, подскажите, как можно задать имя инстанса во время создание через Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, снова сам разобрался. Нужно в обязательном порядке добавить имя и тип к instance_tags:

```
instance_tags:
      Name: "Instance-01"
      Type: ''
```